Syntax Highlighting Issue with .ts and .tsx Files in VSCode (Dark Mode)
I'm experiencing an issue with my .ts and .tsx files in VSCode. The syntax highlighting seems broken, as my files appear with a strange red background, making it very difficult to work with. I’m using dark mode, and this issue suddenly appeared. Here's a screenshot showing how my files look:
[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/gwS6GBiI.png)
I’ve tried the following:
Restarting VSCode
Reinstalling the extensions related to TypeScript/TSX
Changing themes
Checking for any issues in my settings.json
None of these solutions fixed the problem. I’m not sure if this is a problem with my VSCode configuration or an extension issue.
Does anyone have any ideas on how to resolve this? Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance!

The minimap is completly red because vscode reports an error on every line. What does it say for the lines in the main window? They all have a red ~ at the end of each line.

Check the Problems tab in the bottom pane for an error message, and then paste it into the question if you still have a question about. what it means

here is what is showing
Replace 'react-native-vector-icons/Feather';␍ with "react-native-vector-icons/Feather";eslintprettier/prettier
[{
"resource": "/d:/FREE_APP/prestataire-app/src/components/ui/MarkServiceComplete.tsx",
"owner": "eslint",
"code": {
"value": "prettier/prettier",
"target": {
"$mid": 1,
"external": "https://github.com/prettier/eslint-plugin-prettier#options",
"path": "/prettier/eslint-plugin-prettier",
"scheme": "https",
"authority": "github.com",
"fragment": "options"
}
